# SQL Server SUM(Values)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following query that works perfectly well. The query sums the values in a given day.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(fldValue) AS 'kWh',
    DAY(fldDateTime) AS 'Day',
    MONTH(fldDateTime) AS 'Month',
    YEAR(fldDateTime) AS 'Year'            
FROM 
    [Data.tblData]
WHERE 
    tblData_Id IN (SELECT DISTINCT tblData_Id 
                   FROM [Data.tblData])
GROUP BY    
    YEAR(fldDateTime), MONTH(fldDateTime), DAY(fldDateTime),
    tblData_Id,fldDateTime
ORDER BY 
    YEAR(fldDateTime), MONTH(fldDateTime), DAY(fldDateTime)
```

The problem I have is that it sums from midnight to midnight, I need it to sum the values after midnight ( >= Midnight) then up to midnight of the next day. The reason for this is the data that comes in for a day, is always after midnight. For example the first logged data will be '2016-01-01 00:01:00', the final logged data will be '2016-01-02 00:00:00'. This is how the hardware works that sends me the data.

I would like to know how to encapsulate >= midnight to midnight in the query.

Dataset:

```
DateTime    Value
20/03/2016 00:30    69.00
20/03/2016 01:00    69.00
20/03/2016 01:30    69.00
20/03/2016 02:00    69.00
20/03/2016 02:30    69.00
20/03/2016 03:00    69.00
20/03/2016 03:30    11.88
20/03/2016 04:00    0.52
20/03/2016 04:30    1.51
20/03/2016 05:00    2.22
20/03/2016 05:30    2.11
20/03/2016 06:00    0.05
20/03/2016 06:30    6.78
20/03/2016 07:00    14.79
20/03/2016 07:30    1.57
20/03/2016 08:00    1.51
20/03/2016 08:30    4.81
20/03/2016 09:00    0.11
20/03/2016 09:30    8.99
20/03/2016 10:00    10.06
20/03/2016 10:30    15.28
20/03/2016 11:00    3.22
20/03/2016 11:30    1.73
20/03/2016 12:00    19.10
20/03/2016 12:30    2.08
20/03/2016 13:00    2.61
20/03/2016 13:30    0.84
20/03/2016 14:00    8.65
20/03/2016 14:30    2.37
20/03/2016 15:00    16.34
20/03/2016 15:30    12.66
20/03/2016 16:00    2.64
20/03/2016 16:30    0.19
20/03/2016 17:00    3.91
20/03/2016 17:30    2.39
20/03/2016 18:00    0.57
20/03/2016 18:30    1.30
20/03/2016 19:00    5.06
20/03/2016 19:30    17.45
20/03/2016 20:00    13.04
20/03/2016 20:30    5.00
20/03/2016 21:00    7.47
20/03/2016 21:30    5.09
20/03/2016 22:00    0.33
20/03/2016 22:30    5.29
20/03/2016 23:00    15.33
20/03/2016 23:30    5.39
21/03/2016 00:00    6.74
```

Thank you in advance.

The expected sum output value for 20/03/2016 is: 662.98

The output table will look like:

```
SumValue    Day Month   Year    Meter Id
659.18  20  3   2016    6
251.37  21  3   2016    6
279.03  22  3   2016    6
280.03  23  3   2016    6
284.22  24  3   2016    6
310.12  25  3   2016    6
320.84  26  3   2016    6
269.29  27  3   2016    6
276.11  28  3   2016    6
279.11  29  3   2016    6
```

The value column is the sum of the values for that day, made up of lots of individual times.

Comment: Your going to need to pass the time through your where clause

Comment: You can use case statements in your GROUP BY, you know.

Comment: could we trouble you for the table design? Might be able to knock up something a little cheekier and easier for you

Comment: The table designed as:    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [tblMeterData_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
 [fldDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [fldValue] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
 [fldBatchId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL The table it is going to will be     [tblDailyRoundup_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [fldValue] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
 [fldValueFrom] [date] NULL,
 [fldValueTo] [date] NULL,
 [tblData_Id] [int] NULL,
 [fldDateCompleted] [timestamp] NOT NULL

Comment: Hi clifton_h, I did think about that, but the dates can be over several years. I was thinking about creating reference table with every conceivable date, but I would would need to lots, as the data may be in seconds, minutes, 5 minutes etc.

Comment: You defined attribute fldDateCompleted as timestamp. Be advised that timestamp is not a date datatype, it's deprecated and used for row versioning.

Comment: If you want to store a date, use date, datetime or datetime2. Timestamp can not be used to store dates or times (despite its name).

Comment: @Honeybadger, I was using it to show the latest date that the summing of the data was completed, as sometimes, they send me corrected data. Should it not be used in this way? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below query for summing up the midnight value with previous day.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(fldValue) AS 'kWh',
    CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), fldDateTime, 108)='00:00:00' THEN DAY(fldDateTime)-1 ELSE DAY(fldDateTime) END AS 'Day',
    MONTH(fldDateTime) AS 'Month',
    YEAR(fldDateTime) AS 'Year'            
FROM 
    Data.[tblData]
GROUP BY    
    YEAR(fldDateTime), MONTH(fldDateTime),CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), fldDateTime, 108)='00:00:00' THEN DAY(fldDateTime)-1 ELSE DAY(fldDateTime) END

ORDER BY 
    YEAR(fldDateTime), MONTH(fldDateTime), CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), fldDateTime, 108)='00:00:00' THEN DAY(fldDateTime)-1 ELSE DAY(fldDateTime) END
```

Sample output :

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly. Just so I understand the CASE statement, I can change the summing to months etc by changing the conversion number (ie 102).

Comment: Great.. Give an up-vote if you agree with this solution... :)

Answer (score 1):

First, I have no idea what the `WHERE` clause is doing, so I'm going to remove it.

Second, don't use single quotes for column names.

Third, your `GROUP BY` clause is too complicated.  You only need to include the unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`.

Finally, the key idea is to subtract one hour from the values everywhere they are used.  Here is a simple method:

```
SELECT SUM(fldValue) AS kWh,
       DAY(newdt) AS [Day],
       MONTH(newdt) AS [Month],
       YEAR(newdt) AS [Year]           
FROM (SELECT d.*, DATEADD(hour, -1, fldDateTime) as newdt
      FROM Data.tblData d
     ) d
GROUP BY YEAR(newdt), MONTH(newdt), DAY(newdt)
ORDER BY YEAR(newdt), MONTH(newdt), DAY(newdt)
```

Comment: I have added a dataset, to show what I mean. This data comes in half hours, but may get send in minutes at another time.

Comment: Are you saying that subtracting an hour does not answer your question?

Comment: I needed to add some time @Unnikrishnan R got the result I was looking for (above)

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as @Gordon but you can subtract one minute instead of one hour.

```
SELECT SUM(fldValue) AS kWh,
   DAY(newdt) AS [Day],
   MONTH(newdt) AS [Month],
   YEAR(newdt) AS [Year]           
FROM (SELECT d.*, DATEADD(minute, -1, fldDateTime) as newdt
  FROM Data.tblData d
 ) d
GROUP BY YEAR(newdt), MONTH(newdt), DAY(newdt)
ORDER BY YEAR(newdt), MONTH(newdt), DAY(newdt)
```

Comment: Hi It needs to be greater than midnight then less than midnight of the following day. The data is coming from a data logger that monitors plant equipment and all of the different plant sends data in different times, sometimes its seconds, sometimes its minutes and sometime it half hours. There around a 100 different times currently - yes, it is a nightmare!

Comment: Please add required output too.

Comment: I have added the expected output in the original comment,

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @tempTable table ([DateTime] datetime, Value Float)

insert into @tempTable ([DateTime], [Value])
select convert(datetime,'20/03/2016 00:30',103), 69.00 union all
select convert(datetime,'20/03/2016 01:00',103), 69.00 union all
select convert(datetime,'21/03/2016 00:00',103), 6.74

select * from @tempTable

select [sum] = SUM(value), [year] = year(DT), [month] = month(DT), [day] = day(DT)
from (select Value, DT = dateadd(second, -1, [DateTime]) from @tempTable) x
group by year(DT), month(DT), day(DT)
```